# Doctrine Check if relationship exists?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a collection of objects that I'm looping over and I want to check if the relationship exists for that particular object before echoing anything out because it otherwise crashes saying it's null.

Something like:

```
foreach (objects as object)
object->relationship()->getName()
endforeach
```

If i do something like..

```
if (object->relationship()):
endif;
```

Then it doesn't stop it from crashing because it has an ID, it's just that id is invalid and so it crashes because it can't find anything based on where the id is pointing towards.